# taskbar doesnt show used apps, features, and more

Tags: windows-10, drivers, taskbar, bug

So I was just about to study React Native. I downloaded Expo (which is a React library that helps with React Native) and I tried to open my project on my smartphone, but for some reason it did not work and I realised that I may have to sign off from my laptop's account.  I reconnected and suddenly my taskbar started to mess things up.  I currently can't see any app in-use and when I pin apps to the taskbar it doesnt show the icon, but it exists and my battery icon and volume are completely gone.  Also when I enter full screen in YouTube it doesn't cover the taskbar so it hides a part of the video.  I tried many solutions that I found online and none of them helped, including:

- restarting windows explorer
- updating drivers (not all of them but some)
- shutting the computer down and turning it back on
- scanning for windows issued at the cmd
- changing the taskbar settings which btw shows a completely unchangeable mode for my battery, volume and more...

[image]

Comment: What have you installed that destroyed Windows so thoroughly? Looks like you were infected with a very clumsy virus.

Comment: any recommendations for an anti virus? avg sucks

Comment: Yes, AVG is sub par, and no, we don't recommend software here.

Comment: ok, anyway i did a full deep scan with avg and a smart scan with avira. both found nothing so i guess a virus is not the problem

Comment: update: i just clicked on restart on my avg and it finally updated my computer (another problem i always had was that when i clicked update and restart on the start bar it wouldnt do a thing) and after this update everything is back to normal! plz keep this thread unlocked incase something happens, but i wont reply (wasnt a virus after all :)   )